# PHP equivalent to max function in lodash/underscore

Tags: php

Is there a PHP v5.5 equilavent to [max](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#max) for lodash/underscore?

Basically I would like to be able to do something similar to this:

```
$characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 40 }
];

max($characters, 'age');
// → { 'name': 'fred', 'age': 40 };
```

Comment: Not built-in.  Why not make one?  Just loop over the array and figure out which is biggest.

Comment: Why not sort you array by age using usort, then get the top entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a port of Underscore called [Underscore.php](http://brianhaveri.github.io/Underscore.php/) which provides the max function (as well as many other Underscore functions).

From its [documentation](http://brianhaveri.github.io/Underscore.php/#max):

```
$stooges = array(
  array('name'=>'moe', 'age'=>40),
  array('name'=>'larry', 'age'=>50),
  array('name'=>'curly', 'age'=>60)
);
__::max($stooges, function($stooge) { return $stooge['age']; });
// array('name'=>'curly', 'age'=>60)
```

Answer (score 4):

Might be a slicker way, but here's one:

```
$result = $characters[array_search(max($a=array_column($characters, 'age')),$a)];

print_r($result);

(
    [name] => fred
    [age] => 40
)
```

Using a sort:

```
array_multisort(array_column($characters, 'age'), SORT_DESC, $characters);

print_r($characters[0]);
```

NOTE: `array_column` requires PHP >= 5.5.0

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP 5.5's [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to tweak the structure of the original array slightly:

```
$characters = [
  [ 'name' => 'barney', 'age' => 36 ],
  [ 'name' => 'fred',   'age' => 40 ],
  [ 'name' => 'wilma',  'age' => 35 ],
  [ 'name' => 'betty',  'age' => 34 ],
];

arsort($simple = array_column($characters, 'age', 'name'));
$max = array_slice($simple, 0, 1);

var_dump($max);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to iterate over them and just look, where the biggest value is:

```
// All examples php 5.4+
$characters = [
  [ 'name'=> 'barney', 'age'=> 36 ],
  [ 'name'=> 'fred',   'age'=> 26 ],
  [ 'name'=> 'fred4',   'age'=> 23 ],
  [ 'name'=> 'fred5',   'age'=> 82 ],
  [ 'name'=> 'fred6',   'age'=> 24 ],
];

if(!isset($characters[0]['age']) { die('wrong array structure'); }

$maxLocation = 0;
foreach($characters as $position => $value) {
    if($value['age'] > $characters[$maxLocation]['age']) {
        $maxLocation = $position;
    }
} 

var_dump($characters[$maxLocation]);
```

Ordering them might be an overkill, however, if you need to act on them later:

```
usort($characters, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['age'] === $b['age']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a['age'] < $b['age'] ? 1 : -1;
});

var_dump($characters[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the solutions, I guess the answer to this problem is:

> No, there isnt any equivalent to "max" in PHP

But I will upvote every answer that gave me an alternative method to do it. Thanks guys.